# How to avoid avoid broken pipes using c# and Python?

Tags: c#, python, pipe

When trying to use stdin and stdout in C# (Unity) to pipe to a Python process, I get about a dozen or so transactions and the process breaks and the error "ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed."

After trying several of the more obvious things, I'm bringing the problem here perhaps someone know just the right technique.  Thanks in advance.

Here's the C# Startup code:

```
Process pyProcess;    // <=== fixed
ProcessStartInfo pyStartInfo;
public StreamReader pyStreamReader;
public StreamWriter pyStreamWriter;


public void startPython()
{

    // Create new process start info
    pyStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pyPath)
    {
         UseShellExecute = false,
         RedirectStandardInput = true,
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         Arguments = pyApp + " " + pyArgs
    };

pyProcess = new Process { StartInfo = pyStartInfo };
pyProcess.Start();
pyStreamReader = pyProcess.StandardOutput;
pyStreamWriter = pyProcess.StandardInput;
pyStreamWriter.WriteLine("Hello!");
string str = pyStreamReader.ReadLine();
Debug.LogFormat(str + "\n");
}


void Start()
{
    if(testPython == true)
        startPython();
```

Here is the fragment that generates data sent to python at each update...

```
if (controller.testPython)
{
    string str, python;
    str = String.Format("data to send");
    pyStreamWriter.DiscardBufferedData();  #<==== fixed
    pyStreamWriter.WriteLine(str);
    python = pyStreamReader.ReadLine();
    Debug.LogFormat("python says: " + python + "\n");
    }
```

And here is the simplified python process that's echoing the data

```
while True:
    cmd = input()        # read a command from c#
    print(cmd)  # process the cmd, here we just echo it back to c#
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little experimentation, I discovered that adding

```
pyStreamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
```

before

```
pyStreamWriter.WriteLine(str);
```

solves the main problem and this simple form of piping seems to work, at least for hundreds of transactions that I observed.

I also had to declare pyProcess outside the scope so the code so that its handle is not released.  That resolved the ObjectDisposed exception.